# How to break the line every n-th time when results are written individually into a file?

Tags: line, break, python-3.6

I have this program, which takes the values from 2 separate files `(ex1.idl and ex2.idl)`, performs a calculation and writes the results into a different file (ex3.txt). It all works well and the output are the results in one large line.

I am looking for an easy way to break the line every 10th element in the output, like this:

> 100 200 500 600 120 180 400 450 900 100
>
> 100 200 700 600 620 580 400 450 900 400
>
> 200 200 700 800 620 580 400 450 800 300

```
with open('ex1.idl') as f1, open('ex2_1.idl') as f2:
    with open('ex3.txt', 'w') as f3:

        start_line = 905        #reading from this line forward
        for i in range(start_line - 1):
            next(f1)
            next(f2)
        f1 = list(map(float, f1.read().split()))
        f2 = list(map(float, f2.read().split()))
        for result in map(lambda v : v[0]/v[1], zip(f1,f2)):
            if(f3.count()%10 != 0):
                f3.write(str(result) + ' ')
            else:
                f3.write(str(result) + '\n')
```

I thank you in advance for a solution (advice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it ouf for future viewers:

```
for i, result in enumerate(map(lambda v : v[0]/v[1], zip(f1,f2)), start=1):
            if(i%10 != 0):
                f3.write(' ' + str('{0:.9f}'.format(result)))
            else:
                f3.write(' ' + str('{0:.9f}'.format(result)) + '\n')
```